# Angular and ParseSDK Javascript CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am creating a service to get the values saved as "FirstName" in a Row "name", when save is ok i have the values in the database, but when i try to get this values  i have something like this:

### people:

### -

All the values in the list empty but i don't know  why this happen if it is a problem in the controller or in the service.

```
<script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    people
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
var People = Parse.Object.extend("People");
var peoples= new People();
peoples.set("name", "FirstName");

peoples.save(null),{
    success:function(peoples){
        peoples.save();
    }
}


var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "PeopleService", function($scope, PeopleService){
  $scope.people = PeopleService.getPeople();
}]);

app.service("PeopleService", function($q){
  var people = null;

  return {
  getPeople: function(){
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          people = [];
          var queryObject = new Parse.Query(People);
          queryObject.find({
            success: function (results) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var result = results[i];
                people.push(result.get("name"));
              }
              deferred.resolve(people);
            },
            error: function (error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
            }
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `$scope.people` value from the success callback function of `parse.com` call.

**Code**

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "PeopleService", function($scope, PeopleService){
  PeopleService.getPeople().then(function(data){ //success fn
     $scope.people = data
  },function(data){ //error fn
     $scope.people = data
  });
}]);
```

Comment: after set the $scope.people with the code , i am having this error. Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: @alsuelo use `track by $index` inside `ng-repeat` like `<li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person}}</li>`

Comment: works perfect, i want to ask you if you know how to create a service to save, edit and delete. I'll really appreciate it.